# R mice package error: "Error in .imputation.level2 ... clusteres with partially missing level-2 data"

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to use the mice package to run multiple imputation for many variables in my dataset. This data is multi-level, as each observation has a person and a team attached to it. Some variables should vary within a person and by team, while others should stay the same within all responses from a person. A sample of my code is below:

- "starts" is my data.
- "personlevel" is a vector of variable names
  that stay the same within person.
- "teamlevel" is a vector of
  variable names that rely more heavily on the specific team.

```
predmatrix<-quickpred(starts)

predmatrix[personlevel, 'PERNER'] <- -2 #designate PersonID as cluster variable for person-level characteristics

predmatrix[teamlevel, 'team_id'] <- -2 # designates teamID as cluster variable for team level characteristics

imputation_specs<-is.na(starts)
imputation_specs[,onlypred]<-FALSE  # this matrix will tell mice where to impute or not, so I'm setting all of the solely predictor variables to "FALSE"

# Determine imputation methods

# Create imputation with 0 iterations to generate a process-control object
mi1 <- mice(starts, maxit = 0)
mi_methods <- mi1$method

# Set imputation methods
mi_methods<-ifelse(colnames(starts) %in% personlevel, "2lonly.pmm", 
       ifelse(colnames(starts) %in% teamlevel, "2l.pmm", "")) # this sets predictor only columns to no method, person-level columns to 2lonly.pmm, and team-level columns to 2l.pmm

# Run imputations 
test_MI_2<-mice(starts, pred=predmatrix, 
                where=imputation_specs,method=mi_methods, m=2, print=FALSE)
```

When I run the mice function, I am receiving an error that says `Error in .imputation.level2(y = y, ry = ry, x = x, type = type, wy = wy,  :  Method 2lonly.pmm found the following clusters with partially missing level-2 data: 70024886 Method 2lonly.mean can fix such inconsistencies.`

70024886 is a person ID (cluster). I've looked at this person's data and I can't figure out why this cluster of data is causing issues within the imputation while other observations wouldn't. Does anyone understand more about what this error is signifying as the problem? I can't find anything online about this specific error, and I'd rather stick to .pmm as my method for imputation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occurring in my code because some variables were incorrectly listed as "person-level" when really they varied by team. So, mice was seeing variation within a person where there shouldn't be and this caused the code to be unable to run. Fixing the categorization of these variables removed the error immediately.